# Compare 2 files [Bash]

Tags: bash

I want to compare 2 files and output only scanned macs which arent in the file which have all macs manually stored. I have tried creating 2 arrays and then saving scanned macs in scanned macs and in the other all the macs i have called all macs. How i can compare these 2 and output only macs that aren't in all macs arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash
for item1 in "${allMacs[@]}"; do
    for item2 in "${scannedMacs[@]}"; do
        if [[ $item1 == $item2 ]];then
            echo "$item1" >> final.txt
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Presuming file f1 contains the scanned macs and file f2 contains all macs, and you want to find the macs present in f1 that are not in f2, you can do this in one line using `grep -v -f f2 f1`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You want the 477 Macs that are not scanned as the output?

Comment: example : if the first scanned mac is not in 497 macs as output i only want only that mac

Comment: Oh. I thought you were trying to achieve something else, my bad

Comment: your previous solution didnt worked for me, anyways Thanks